# How do I create a subdomain and then have it forward to a subfolder?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

Say I have the site blog.mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com. I want to make sure that if people type in blog.mydomain.com, that it'll redirect to www.mydomain.com/blog.
(I know the question is usually asked the other way around..)

I found and edited the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is this correct?
And: Do I need to create a record in my DNS to make the subdomain? (since this .htaccess stuff is on the regular domain of course and not on the blog.mydomain.com..)

Comment: You do not need a dns entry for this, what you have should work. Without testing I can't guarantee as Apache ReWrites can get messy very quickly.

Comment: @Scott: Thanks. I'm going to try out Bob's suggestion and won't create a dns entry for it..

Comment: Your rewrite code should work **as is** without any modification however you should use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]` for RewriteCond.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/blog/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and what Malachi dud already? I see OP has included [R=301,L] (L tells the web server to stop processing rewrites in this file).

Comment: I like escaping out the . in the RewriteCond line, and L seems to be a religious question!  :)

Comment: Fair enough. Escaping makes sense. And you are definitely correct about 'L' always causing more debate than deserved.

Comment: Thanks, Bob.. I'm gonna try that one out. (And yes, I know it's pretty much the same.. just a tad different)

Comment: And why not `^blog\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]`?